Redshift query with regexp_replace works in Redshift console but not Python lambda
One of the fields in my Redshift table is structured like {event_type} 2024-01-01, so I am using regexp_replace to remove the date from the event type. I am calling Redshift via a Python Lambda like this
client = boto3.client("cluster-name", aws_region, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_session_token)

query = """
    select id, regexp_replace(event_type, '\\s+\\d{4}-\\d{2}$', '') as event
    from table
"""

But the regex expression does not work, all results returned by the query still have the date attached.
However, if I try the query in the Redshift console, the field is transformed correctly.
I assumed it was something to do with the \\s and the escape characters, I tried it with three and four slashes instead of two, but that didn't work

It looks like you mis-formed the replacement string.  You have 3 digit fields separated by '-', not 2.  You are requiring end of line with the '$', and starting with whitespace so you cannot match with this pattern.  Try (untested)
regexp_replace(event_type, '\\s+\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$', '')


There's no need to use regex here, just strip off the rightmost 10 characters (the length of an ISO date string) and then any trailing spaces using string functions:
query='''
    select id, trim(left(event_type, len(event_type)-10)) as event
    from table
'''


Use a python "raw string" instead:
query = r"""
    select id, regexp_replace(event_type, '\\s+\\d{4}-\\d{2}$', '') as event
    from table
"""

This way it won't strip out one of each pair of backslashes.
